# Detect My page rendering in Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I have followed this link [ChromeApp](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html) for my chromeApp

I want to detect that Is my HTML page rendering on ChromeApp?

```
if(chromeApp){
//do this
}
else{
//do this
}
```

Comment: sorry I have just update link, My basic requirement is to Manage my alert code.I am using <webview> to call my page.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the general question: Outside of the webview you can detect if you are rendering in a Chrome App by:

```
  if (chrome && chrome.app && chrome.app.runtime)
    // chrome app.
  else
    // open web.
```

(Taken from [gapi-chrome-apps.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/gapi-chrome-apps-lib/gapi-chrome-apps.js))

To answer the intent of the question, "How can detect and not show alert messages for content in a webview", you may wish to change the user agent and use that to detect. See this [test code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/test/data/extensions/platform_apps/web_view/common/useragent/bootstrap.js&sq=package%3achromium&type=cs&q=file%3auseragent%20file%3atest%20file%3aboot&l=1) for more. Here's the idea, though:

```
webview.setUserAgentOverride(webview.getUserAgent() + ' in a webview');
```

Also, you can support alert dialogs with the [change 19679002: : Implement dialog API](https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/19679002) (not quite in Chrome stable I think). The following should illustrate:

From the host:

```
webview.addEventListener('dialog', function(e) {
    // Check e.messageType, e.g. it may be 'alert'.
    // Use e.messageText
    // Unblock the guest content wity e.dialog.ok();
  });
```